# Python script freezes when writing in files inside Desktop folder

Tags: python, permissions, binary, freeze

**SOLVED**

> chkdsk /f and rebooting fixed the problem.

**Problem.** Python script freezes when doing multiple writings in files located inside 'Desktop' folder. This happens at around 10-15's file. Doesn't matter what kind of file, but amount of files, that script have modified (around 10-15).

If they are moved outside 'Desktop' folder (C:\Users\User\Desktop) or python script is running by CMD with admin rights, then there is no freeze.

**EDIT** This behaviour has nothing to do with specific file. Because I've experimented with any random files I found. Also I tried to delete file at which script froze with prior file. The result was the same — freeze after exact amount of files.

Also when I deleted first 9 files. Then script succesfully modified files where previosly it froze. But again when around 10-15 files passed script freeze.

Here is an example of code where script freezes:

```
root = ...
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
       file = (os.path.join(path, name))
        print("1")
       with open(file, 'r+b') as f: #Here script freezes
           print("2") #No matter what the file is
           f.seek(1)  #but iterations of loop are limited to 10-15
           f.write(b'\x0a')
```

Python 3.10, Windows 10(updated recently), Windows Defender deactivated.

- Replacing with() by open()+close() doesnt help at all.
- I tried script on .txt, .css, .bin files — everywhere the same freeze occurs, but at different amount of files that script went through (~10-20 cycles in the above code example before freeze)

**Q.** Why does this happen without Exceptions, Errors or notifications by System? What causes a script to freeze? And why the freeze happens after 10-20 files were successfully modified?

Comment: Instead of printing 2, you could print the file name to see which file it freezes on and if it's the same one every time

Comment: @OmOWalker it doesn't matter which file. Maybe I didnt wrote clear enough. But only amount of files that script have passed in loop matters. 

If I delete all first 10-20 files that script passed successfully with those on which it froze , it will pass another 10-20 files and freeze. 

It works with any random files I put in folder.